# How can I switch between 2 images on click in Vue js(Nuxt)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt js and I have 2 images. When I click the first image, it should change to the second and when I click the second it should change back to the first image and so on.

This is what I have so far. I am switching between the srcs of the image like this:

```
<template>
<img id="test" src="../assets/menu.svg" @click="change" />
</template>

<script>
change(): any {
    const img1 = '../assets/menu.svg';
    const img2 = '../assets/cross.svg';
    const imgElement = document.getElementById('test');
    imgElement.src = imgElement.src === img1 ? img2 : img1;   <-- I think this is the problem
  }
</script>
```

The error on that line: `Object is possibly null.`

Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a computed property:

```js
<template>
<img id="test" :src="imgSrc" @click="imgClicked = !imgClicked" />
</template>

<script>
  data () {
    return {
      imgClicked: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    imgSrc: function () {
      return this.imgClicked ? '../assets/menu.svg' : '../assets/cross.svg'
    }
  }
</script>
```

If I remember correctly, you might have to use require if have a dynamic src: `require('~/assets/menu.svg')`

Comment: There may be a problem with only returning a string instead of a module request as the image source. The computed property should return `require('../assets/menu.svg')`.

EDIT: you edited while I typed, nevermind :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for some reason, I only see the image cross.svg when I click. It doesn't switch to the image menu.svg. I would like menu.svg to be there as a first image and then switch to cross.svg on click. This is what I have `imgClicked = false;
  get imgSrc(): any {
    return this.imgClicked
      ? require('~/assets/menu.svg')
      : require('~/assets/cross.svg');
  } `

Comment: Are you also changing the value of imgClicked in the `@click` directive, as written in the example? Otherwise, imgClicked will always be false (thus return cross.svg).

Comment: Did you change the `@click` property on the image?

Comment: My template line is the same as yours(```<img
                id="test"
                :src="imgSrc"
                class="w-6 h-4"
                @click="imgClicked != imgClicked"
              />```), is there a way through which I can load menu.svg as the first image and after the click change to cross.svg, then back and forth?

Comment: You can swap the arguments in the computed property if you need the inverse behaviour.

Comment: @Excalibaard I can't really see the inverse behaviour if the image doesn't change at all :( It remains the same on click.

Comment: @AlyssaAlex My bad, it should be @click="imgClicked = !imgClicked", I've updated my answer

Comment: Oh yeah! :D Thanks a lot!